# Value of state imported from custom hook not showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state, react-custom-hooks

I created a custom hook, Custom.js:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import Clarifai from 'clarifai';

const app = new Clarifai.App({
    apiKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
})

const Custom = () => {

    const [input, setInput] = useState('');
    const [imgUrl, setImgUrl] = useState('');

    function onInputChange (text) {
        setInput(text);
    }

    useEffect(()=>{  
        setImgUrl(input)
    }, [input])


    function onSubmit () {
        console.log('submitted');
        console.log(imgUrl)

        app.models.predict(Clarifai.COLOR_MODEL, "https://www.takemefishing.org/getmedia/bde1c54e-3a5f-4aa3-af1f-f2b99cd6f38d/best-fishing-times-facebook.jpg?width=1200&height=630&ext=.jpg").then(
        function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        function(err) {
            // there was an error
        }
        );
    }

    return {input, imgUrl, onInputChange, onSubmit}
}
 
export default Custom;
```

I imported this custom hook into 2 of my other components, FaceRecognition.js and InputForm.js.

FaceRecognition.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Custom from '../Custom';

const FaceRecognition = () => {
    const { imgUrl } = Custom();
function yes (){
    return console.log(imgUrl)
}
yes()

    return (
        <div>
            <h1 className='white'>The url is {ImgUrl} </h1>
            <img width={'50%'} alt=''src={imgUrl}/>
        </div>
    );
}
 
export default FaceRecognition;
```

ImportForm.js:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './InputForm.css'
import Custom from '../Custom';


const InputForm = () => {

    const { onInputChange, onSubmit } = Custom();

   

    return (
        <>
            <p className='txt f3'>Enter image link address</p>
            <div className='center flex w-70'>
                <input type='text' className='w-80 pa1' onChange={(e)=>onInputChange(e.target.value)}/>
                <button className='w-20 pa1 pointer' onClick={onSubmit}>Detect</button>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
 
export default InputForm;
```

The functions `onSubmit` and `onImputChange` work as expected for `InputForm.js` and the value of `imgUrl` logs on the console when function `onSubmit` runs, as expected. But the `imgUrl` state which is a string fails to show up between the h1 tags `<h1 className='white'>The url is {imgUrl} boy</h1>` from my `FaceRecognition.js` snippet above, and it also doesn't work as the `src` of the image `<img width={'50%'} alt=''src={imgUrl}/>` below the h1 tag. This is my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

React hooks don't magically share state. You've two separate instances of this `Custom` function, each with their own `useState` hook. I say "function" because you've also mis-named your hook. All React hooks should be named with a "use-" prefix so React can identify it and apply the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) against it.

## Solution

If you want separate instances of your `useCustom` hook to share state then the state needs to be lifted to a common component to be shared. For this you should use a React Context.

Example:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Clarifai from 'clarifai';

const app = new Clarifai.App({
    apiKey: 'XXXXXXXXX'
});

const CustomContext = createContext({
  input: '',
  imgUrl: '',
  onInputChange: () => {},
  onSubmit: () => {}
});

const useCustom = () => useContext(CustomContext);

const CustomProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');
  const [imgUrl, setImgUrl] = useState('');

  function onInputChange (text) {
    setInput(text);
  }

  useEffect(()=>{  
    setImgUrl(input);
  }, [input]);

  function onSubmit () {
    console.log('submitted');
    console.log(imgUrl);

    app.models.predict(
      Clarifai.COLOR_MODEL,
      "https://www.takemefishing.org/getmedia/bde1c54e-3a5f-4aa3-af1f-f2b99cd6f38d/best-fishing-times-facebook.jpg?width=1200&height=630&ext=.jpg"
    ).then(
      function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      },
      function(err) {
        // there was an error
      }
    );
  }

  return (
    <CustomContext.Provider value={{ input, imgUrl, onInputChange, onSubmit }}>
      {children}
    </CustomContext.Provider>
  );
}

export {
  CustomContext,
  useCustom
};
 
export default CustomProvider;
```

Usage:

Wrap your app with your `CustomProvider` component.

```
import CustomProvider from '../path/to/CustomProvider';

...

return (
  <CustomProvider>
    <App />
  </CustomProvider>
);
```

Import and use the `useCustom` hook in consumers.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useCustom } from '../path/to/CustomProvider';

const FaceRecognition = () => {
  const { imgUrl } = useCustom();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(imgUrl);
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className='white'>The url is {ImgUrl}</h1>
      <img width={'50%'} alt='' src={imgUrl}/>
    </div>
  );
}
 
export default FaceRecognition;
```

...

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './InputForm.css'
import { useCustom } from '../path/to/CustomProvider';

const InputForm = () => {
  const { onInputChange, onSubmit } = useCustom();

  return (
    <>
      <p className='txt f3'>Enter image link address</p>
      <div className='center flex w-70'>
        <input
          type='text'
          className='w-80 pa1'
          onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button
          className='w-20 pa1 pointer'
          onClick={onSubmit}
        >
          Detect
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
 
export default InputForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put your return statement inside the .then of the predict

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).